# Setting up new Mac with old Macbook data

Tags: macbook-pro, data-transfer

I have an old Mac(2010) and want to setup new MB Pro(2015). I want it the way I not only copy all settings but all installed applications(GUI based, command lines) as well as data. I found this [tool](https://support.apple.com/en-ap/HT204350), I wonder whether it's suffice? Also, new Macs don't have ethernet, will it be OK to transfer WiFi in multiple sessions?

I have around 250GB of data.

**Update**:

I was suggested to use firewire or Thunderbolt. Here is the image of ports on my existing old 2010 Macbook. Which of them is the one mentioned?

[image]

Comment:  Unfortunately, that model does not have a FireWire or Thunderbolt port.

Comment: @ArchonOSX means I manually do all stuff.

Comment: Do you have a USB hard drive? You could clone the old computer drive to that and then migrate to the new computer. Unless you want to tear the old computer apart and drop the hard drive into a SATA drive adapter. Otherwise, you will have to try a network transfer.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it through WiFi, but a faster option is [targeted](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH19021?locale=en_US) mode.

You will need a FireWire cable to do this.

Migration assistant copies your home folder (documents, email, pictures, music, etc.) and preferences to the new computer.

However, it does not copy third party applications by default to the new computer. For that, you will have to make a list of your desired applications and copy each of them from the old computer to the new one. You can use Homebrew and Cask to do this but it is probably more involved than just copying in targeted mode or just re-installing. Homebrew can be used to easily re-install command line apps on the new computer. Migration Assistant does not copy command line apps.

Even if you did copy the GUI apps to the new computer there will probably be a few that no longer work on Yosemite and you will need a newer version.

Good luck!

Comment: What if I have Yosemite at both end? Also I don't have Firewire cable, not sure that even if  it's available in my country, how long will it take to transfer?

Comment: Please check the updated question with image.